# video cdn for android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming

Goal - watch top-ten videos back to back without delay in android app

I read about adaptive streaming(HLS/DASH) cdn like amazon cloudfront, hola, streamable.

Unfortunately, none of their given examples work. Each throws a unique error which I am unable to resolve. Amazon & Streamable, support staff does not respond.

When using [Amazon Cloudfront Tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/streaming-videos-to-mobile-app-users-via-amazon-cloudfront-cdn/) sample app, I was getting following error - "No Viewing App exists for content type - application/octeam-stream",
so I created a VideoPlayerActivity that uses [ExoMedia](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) to play videos.

I get the following error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find
>   configured root for
>   content://com.mysampleapp.fileprovider/s3_lolwow-contentdelivery-mobilehub-2118977425/content/HLS/Popeye_forPresident_512kb-1490367405276/output/2M_v4.m3u8

I modified 'name' attribute in content_delivery_paths.xml because changing name should not make any difference

Original

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="." path="/"/> 
</paths>
```

Modified

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="videos" path="/"/> 
</paths>
```

Now I'm getting the following error

> com.amazon.mysampleapp E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal track
>   renderer error. com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException:
>   com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.ContentDataSource$ContentDataSourceException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory

Multiple attempts later I decided to switch and try streamable.com but encountered this [error](https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidStreamable/issues/2), their support team does not respond to any queries.

Can anyone guide me through this?

Comment: Hey, use https://github.com/lipangit/JieCaoVideoPlayer this player and put you video urls in list. Hope it helps

Comment: CloudFront is good one for streaming purpose, I had used that for Video in PHP web application. Try another tutorial. It seems something wrong with your APP and THe configuration on your APP side.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to streamable.com, I figured the problem and resolved it
https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidStreamable/issues/2#issuecomment-292454278